# Connecting to http-remoting address in Wildfly ActiveMQ Artemis using C# .NET - what am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have a Wildfly instance running ActiveMQ Artemis. How can I set up and connect to an address "http-remoting://x.x.x.x:xxxx" in C# .NET with using a username and password?

```
string url = "amqp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + ipAddress + ":" + port;

try
{
   var address = new Address(url);
   connection = new Connection(address);

   session = new Session(connection);
   Source source = CreateBasicSource();

   // Create a Durable Consumer Source.
   source.Address = topic;
   source.ExpiryPolicy = new Symbol("never");
   source.Durable = 2;
   source.DistributionMode = new Symbol("copy");

   ReceiverLink receiver = new ReceiverLink(session, "test-subscription", source, null);
   LogService.Warning("Connected succesfully to: " + url);
   Consumer_Listener(receiver);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   LogService.Warning("Failed to connect! " + e.Message);
}
```

The above code works, when connecting to an address "amqp://x.x.x.x:xxxx", but does not work if I try to change the address to "http-remoting://x.x.x.x:xxxx". I am unsure on how to change my code, so that it will connect to my desired address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "http-remoting" scheme is implemented by the *Java* WildFly client and it's used for various things, but in the messaging context it's usually used to look up the JMS `ConnectionFactory` and `Destination` in JNDI. Of course, a C# .NET messaging client that speaks AMQP has no notion or need of JNDI since that's really a Java-specific thing.

The issue you're hitting is that WildFly, by default, isn't configured to support AMQP. Even though ActiveMQ Artemis is a multi-protocol broker WildFly really just uses it for JMS support so that's all it's configured for out-of-the-box. In order to enable support for AMQP you'd need to add a new `remote-acceptor` as well as a new `socket-binding`, e.g.:

```xml
<server>
    ...
    <profile>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:15.0">
            <server name="default">
                ...
                <remote-acceptor name="amqp" socket-binding="amqp">
                    <param name="protocols" value="AMQP"/>
                </remote-acceptor>
                ...
            </server>
        </subsystem>
        ...
    </profile>
    ...
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        ...
        <socket-binding name="amqp" port="5672"/>
        ...
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```